# Representation of nulls in Freemarker with Spring Framework

Tags: spring, freemarker

I'm developing an application based on Spring Framerwork. As a view technology I use integrated with the framework Freemarker. Problems occur when java bean that stores data for vizualization have a null in some fields. There is no null conception in Freemarker so it considers that there is no these fields in the bean at all. I suppose problem could be solved by customization of class that copies data from the java bean to freemarker's hash object referred in template. But i haven't found what class does it in Spring. Is there such class and how is it called?

Answer (score 3):

Usually you just deal with nulls directly in the template. E.g:

```
${person.surname!"n/a"}
```

which will print "n/a" in case of a null surname, or just:

```
${person.surname!}
```

which will print out the empty string (nothing) in case of a null surname.

Comment: In this way i need to add "!" after every field. IMHO it would be more convenient to have one piece of code that save me from these annoying "Expression undefined" errors.

Comment: You only put `!` after fields which really can be `null` (or missing), not after all of them. Otherwise you could hide typos. Also, in the cases where a field can be `null`, simply printing nothing is usually not proper, so you have to tell explicitly what to do then. Print `N/A` or `-`, or assume the fields is 0 (when it's in a calculation), or skip printing the field label, etc.

Comment: In most cases it's acceptable for me to have nothing (e.g. zero-length string) in such fields in Freemarker. If i need to replace it with something else than nothing i'll check a field with has_content in freemarker template and place an appropriate value there. If i don't want to have zero-length string in such field in freemarker i'll annotate corresponding field in the java bean with some custom annotation (e.g. @Nullable) and check this annotation while data being copied from the java bean to the freemarker's hash.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "!" operator. Here is an example :

```
${your_property!""}
```

It will print the empty string "" if `your_property` is null.

Answer (score 1):

If any part in your property chain can be null, you can also put parantheses around it to guard against any part being null. E.g. if you pu

```
${person.car.door.color!"<no value"}
```

you only guard against the color being null. But if it could also happen that the door, the car or the whole person is gone missing, you have to put

```
${(person.car.door.color)!"<no value"}
```